# django: if model has related models (ForeignKey) display Fields in main modelform

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys

I have two models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Addimg(models.Model):
    addimages = models.ForeignKey('Post', null=True)
    addimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

I wish to add images to my Post model with the "Addimg" model which works fine so far, but now i want that when I edit my parent model (Post), all the appended "Addimg" models also appear in the form. How could i do that? What would be the simplest solution?

Here is my view which handles my "parent" form:

```
def edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

and my forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Post 
        fields = ('image', 'title',)

class AddimgForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Addimg
        fields = ('addimages', 'addimg',)
```

In my form template I have:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

I would be very happy about any tips or usefull links since i'm very new to django/programming I even don't know the right keywords to search for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it easy thing for django:

in forms.py:

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Post, Addimg, extra=1, fields = ('addimages', 'addimg',))
```

in views.py:

```
from .forms import PostForm, MyFormSet

def manageimages(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = MyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            post.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.someview')
    else:
        formset = MyFormSet(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/myformsettemplate.html', {'formset': formset})
```

and in myformsettemplate.html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
    <div class="third">
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).